# Django mysqlclient not installed

Tags: python, mysql, django, ubuntu

I was working with `sqlite` database in local development .
After uploading project to server `ubuntu` , i installed `mysqlclient` , but when i try to run `makemigrations` command this error occurred :

> ImportError: No module named 'django.db.backends.mysql'
>
> Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
>
> ```
> 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
> ```

When I try to install mysqlclient again , this message will shown :

> Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient in
>   /home/user/Env/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages (1.3.13)

I also checked project env folder and mysql lib exists in `env/python3.5/site-packages` !

settings database :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': 'localhost', 
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: Check you mysql db name and client, as well as your Mysql installation on the server, they to run Django shell and see if you are able to import django.db.backends.mysql

Comment: @arshpreet im able to use mysql in new empty project i created in server directly . it means mysql installed correctly in server And problem is in my project

Comment: OK, Create a virtual environment and do the things accordingly. This will sort out your issue.

Comment: @arshpreet i want to install and use mysql in current virtualenv that all my packages installed on it .

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: @MikhailBurshteyn 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

install pymysql in your python package manager, and add write in your settings.py

```
import pymysql

pymysql.version_info = (1, 3, 13, "final", 0)
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```